# How to detect a tap gesture in subviews

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, touch, uitapgesturerecognizer

Quick question: how do i detect if a tap gesture recognizer is within a subview of the view it is added to? Eg. if i click on an object such as a square that has been added as a subview to a background which a tap gesture recognizer has been added to, how do I detect that it has been tapped?

Comment: Please give clear clarification what you like to do? want to recognize the click on subview?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can grab the point of the tap off the gesture recognizer when your handler method is called respective to any view you wish using `-locationInView:`.  Then, use the following method on UIView: `- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` to get a reference to the actual sub view that was tapped remembering that the point you pass in is in the same coordinate space as the view.

Some code to get you started:

```
CGPoint point = [tapGestureRecognizer locationInView:parentView];
UIView *tappedView = [parentView hitTest:point withEvent:nil];
```

For hit testing to work the view needs to have the `userInteractionEnabled` property set to `YES`.  Many views, such as `UILabel`s have this set to `NO` by default.  So prior to the above:

```
self.subviewOfInterest.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

Answer (score 15):

maybe you should set as:
        **subviews.userInteractionEnabled = YES;**
good luck!

Comment: Damn! This is what i needed. My subview was ignored by gestureRecognizer, and now it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the **`requireGestureRecognizerToFail:`** to recognize the tap on subview please refer [this](https://github.com/AalokParikh/pinch-and-uiguesture) code