# UIGesture is not fireing + removing subview from parent which is not superview

Tags: objective-c, google-maps, uiview, uigesturerecognizer

I have the followinf hierarchy in my screen
ViewController(green bellow the red and blue) that has two subviews that "cover" the area of the UIviewController view

[image]

the blue view is a google map (GMSMapView)

I have another UIView (Black) that has a tapgesture attached to it, on tap it removes itself from its superview.

if I add black to my viewcontrollerview as a subview (adding black to green) then everything works fine

but if I add black to the map (the blue) then the tapgesture is not being called

any Ideas on why that is?

Note: the Map gesture work perfectly.

Comment: Maybe the GMSMapView captures the gesture and stops it from going downward? You could just size and position the view over the top of it instead.

Comment: @Toby nop I have a didTap methods for the map they are not fired either

Comment: You don't know how Google map's view is coded, so there might be weird interactions happening that might not be entirely obvious, perhaps? A workaround is to place google map in another container view and add your black view in that instead.

Answer (score 0):

Since the mapView gestures are not fired as well I'm assuming userInteractions are not enabled for subviews.
For every subView you would need to do this: `self.subviewOfInterest.userInteractionEnabled = YES;.` It is set to NO by default.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10459184/how-to-detect-a-tap-gesture-in-subviews) answer has more explanation.

Comment: mapView gestures ARE fired.

Comment: the comment above suggests otherwise. However, did you check if userInteractions are ebnabled of subview?